# SSIS Data Refresh whilst running

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package which runs every 5 minutes to picks up messages for a data synchronisation from one system to another. The problem is that this process should run for less than 5 minutes, but with high activity periods it can run for 2 hours.

The problem is that another message may be created while the package is doing its work and wont get picked up for 2 hours. We go live in a couple of days and we have not designed the process for concurrent operation as there is stuff to work out around contention and locking etc.

Is there a way that SSIS can continually refresh the workload that it uses in the for each loop container so it will pick up the latest messages, even if they arrive after the scheduled SSIS package started?

I thought about max run time but I don't think it exists with SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop container and a foreach loop container inside.

The for each container could update a variable with number of rows processed, the outer while container can monitor this variable to loop while number of rows > 0, i.e. there are items to process, if there are ever 0 items processed the outer while would finish and end the package.

This means your package would pick up messages for sync, process them, look for more messages, process them, etc ,etc, until no messages have been processed.

However; I don't think a refresh will benefit you, if you have ten items to loop through and it takes 3 minutes and during which an eleventh item arrives, that item will sit until the next 5 minute schedule is executed.

If you have 2000 items to process which takes two hours, the job will run and process those 2000, the 2001 item which arrives during the process will then be handled after two hours and five minutes.

If you refresh the list in the ssis package you may have item 2001 in the queue to be processed after 5 minutes, but you still wouldn't reach it in the queue until 2 hours later when 2000 other items have been processed.

You could in fact end up with a never ending job as it always refreshes with new records that arrive before the queue is depleted.

If you are prioritising within your queue then the refresh would make some sense. If you need to process records quicker then a queue with multiple workers (as you identified) is needed.